# Storage size of empty smallint[] Arrays vs separate table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, storage

I have two options:

**a)** Adding three `smallint[]` (array) attributes to my (main) table, two of them will be empty/unused most of the time and the third, will be used often (technically all 3 could be used at the same time, but it rarely happens).

**b)** Creating a new table with two foreign keys: 1 int-key (main) and 1 smallint-key AND the `smallint[]` array I need.

I want to optimize the database in terms of storage usage and have little to no experience in that regard.

Easier to implement would be the empty array variant. Quick testing the size of an empty smallint array (vs just smallint datatype) gave me chills:

According to pgAdmin 4/postgres its a wooping 140 Byte difference (rule of thumb dummy table test result), which would mean (if true) 280 Bytes down the drain for each dataset/row.

This is opposed to the 24-32 Bytes that ChatGPT claimed.

Comment: How many rows are you going to have?  In my opinion, disk space should not be the primary driver for a database table design.

Comment: Currently? I would assume about 700-1000 per year. If I do my job well, it should rise. "Hardcap" even so there is no true hardcap would be around 7000 per year.

Comment: Huh?, `create table smallint_test(smallint_fld smallint); create table smallint_array_test(smallint_array_fld smallint[]);` then `select pg_table_size('smallint_test'); 0 select pg_table_size('smallint_array_test');  8192`

Comment: Then `insert into smallint_test values (1), (2), (3); insert into smallint_array_test values (array[1,2,3]);`. Then `select pg_table_size('smallint_test'); 8192; select pg_table_size('smallint_array_test'); 16384`.

Comment: Well i ASSUME i did something similar. I created two dummy tables, onces with empty smallint[] and one with empty smallint and filled them with ~70 dummy datasets.

Then i ran:
`SELECT
  'testtable'::regclass AS table_name,
  pg_total_relation_size('testtable') AS total_size,
  pg_total_relation_size('testtable') / pg_stat_get_live_tuples('testtable'::regclass) AS avg_row_size
FROM testtable;`
For each of them and compared the difference. (Total size and row size).
As far as i know the shown numbers are in bytes?

Comment: I apologize for my bad grammar, non-native speaker here. Anyway, i kept the smallint[] and smallint attributes in each dummy table empty. I assumed, that would give me the best estimate about the actual size.

Comment: You're talking about a trivial amount of disk space here.  140 bytes at 1000 rows per year is $0.000002 per year in hard disks.  You are guilty of the crime of premature optimization.

Comment: It would be 280 bytes at 1000 rows per year, but yeah. Table would be better for more sparse smallint[], attributes for more frequently used arrays. I going to sleep over it and decide tomorrow.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `pg_table_size` appears to be counting pages, that is not a good way measure the size of a singe value. Try `pg_column_size` instead.

Comment: "*two of them will be empty/unused most of the time*" - then store `NULL` values for those rows, which will take up no extra space at all.

Comment: Since the purpose of the arrays and their relationships haven't been described, there is insufficient detail on which to base a recommendation. As @TimRoberts mentioned, storage size should not be the primary database design consideration: referential integrity, constraint enforcement, and clarity are far more important. Including the actual DDL in the post for each approach would be much better than using abstract descriptions.

Comment: @Bergi " then store NULL values": I assumed that not used/empty arrays by default have the lowest amount of space needed. Why wouldn't you implement that by default? (as a database language developer)

Comment: @JohnH the arrays are going to store keys related to price variations of room types, so the daily prices are fixed in the booking, even so they will vary depending on occupancy rate. The prices are pretty "fixed" and often only vary +-20€. Technically using a table would be better (if another roomtype pops up, its way easier to implement) but i can't see that one coming. I thought using arrays is better then endless bookID + dateID + categorieID + price_variationID combinations. Ofc the arrays will need proper management. and yes its the only part in the DB i consider using arrays.

Comment: @JohnH I'm not sure what you mean with actual DDL. I am using PostgreSQL 16, pgAdmin 4 v7 and python 3.10 for this project.

Comment: @AndreasM. An *unused* / missing value, the "no value" `NULL`, *does* take the lowest amount of space needed: none. An empty array though is distinct from "no value", it will take at least one word for the length of the array (8 bytes IIRC), though [it appears it actually takes three words](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156423/what-is-the-overhead-for-an-array-in-postgres)

Comment: @Bergi in my dummy table test it saves 41 bytes per row.

Comment: @AndreasM., if I understand correctly, the arrays have references to other tables. I strongly recommend against that approach since it precludes using the database's native mechanisms for enforcing referential integrity on those keys. It's difficult to make concrete recommendations without detailed descriptions of the tables and their relationships. The descriptions should include the actual DDL (**D**ata **D**escription **L**anguage) or other code that creates the tables. As has been mentioned, optimizing for space at this stage is premature.

Comment: @JohnH and Tim Roberts you are correct. Even so I could make it work within the booking/main table it contradicts the database normalization. It's completely irrational to sacrifice that for disk space. Especially if the difference in storage usage is negligible (140/280 bytes sounded alot to me). I'm still not entirely sure how DDL would have helped here but I'm going to provide more database specific context for my further questions. If nothing comes up, I will answer this/my question after work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even so it might be interesting to know, which of these options might have a slight edge over the other, more important questions need to be answered.

The fact that some or most of the arrays in the attribute version of the solution will be empty (or filled with "the same values") indicate that the database normalization is infringed.

Therefore there is only one reasonable solution: Option **b)**

Many thanks to @Tim Roberts and @JohnH for pointing me towards the right direction.